# FlatList infinity scrolling on my code is not working

Tags: javascript, redux, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using RN for the development of an application, one of the components is a list of data, I perform the integration of a flat list to form the list...

```
<FlatList data={this.state.tickets}
         keyExtractor={(item,index) => item._id + Math.random()}
         refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
         onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
         onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
         onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
         ListFooterComponent={this.footerList}
         renderItem={({item}) => 
             <View style={styles.childOneFlat}>
                 <View style={styles.childTwoFlat}>
                     <TouchableOpacity style={styles.childThreeFlat} 
                         onPress={() => {this.goToTask(item)}}>
                             <View style={styles.childFourFlat}>
                                 <Text style={styles.childFiveFlat}> 
                                 {'Ticket N° '+item.taskId}</Text>
                                 <Text style={styles.childSixFlat}>></Text>
                             </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>            
            </View>}>
</FlatList>
```

Sorry for the bad indentation...

my methods :

```
handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({
        page:1,
        refreshing:true
    }, () => {
        this.getTickets();
    });
};

handleLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState((prevStates,nextProps) => ({page: prevStates + 1, 
    loadingMore:true}), () => {this.getTickets();});
};

renderFooter = () => {
    if (!this.state.loadingMore) return null;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'relative',
          width: width,
          height: height,
          paddingVertical: 20,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          marginTop: 10,
          marginBottom: 10,
          borderColor: colors.veryLightPink
        }}
      >
        <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" color='blue'/>
      </View>
    );
  };

handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState(
        {
            page: 1,
            refreshing: true
        },
        () => {
            this._fetchAllBeers();
        }
    );
};
```

Someone may see the error that I could not find.

I would like to be able to incorporate infinity scrolling in the list, thanks to whoever answers from now...

Comment: handleLoadMore triggers when the component is loaded, after that it is impossible to fire it again

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether your `data` prop is updating? `this.state.tickets` should always append the next items which are received from the `this.getTickets();` API call instead of rewriting the whole array.

Comment: That's right, the way I do it?... 

(getState().ticketList.tickets !== null) {
...
}

Comment: I don't understand. Can you elaborate where are you writing this code?

Comment: I still have problems derived from this ... I am changing the state of the component, in a previous state I have an array of 20 elements, in the next one of 40 ... but I still do not have the render to show them in the flatlist

Comment: Try changing the `onEndReachedThreshold` value.

Comment: Was the issue resolved by changing the `onEndReachedThreshold` value? If so I'll edit the answer so that it can help others.